# Address 0x20ec8348e5894855 is not stack'd, malloc'd or (recently) free'd

Tags: c++, callback, shared-libraries

I have two own libraries e.g. "IDA" and "XIDA". And I want to let them communicate together by a callback function.

IDA:
ida.h, ida.cpp, ida_a.h, ida_a.cpp

XIDA:
xida.h, xida.cpp, xida_a.h, xida_a.cpp

IDA:
ida_a.h:

```
class IDA_A
{
private:
    XIDA *mXIDA;
public:
    static int IDA_Callback(void* this_ptr, void *vPara ){
        std::cout << "IDA -- " << "INCOMING CALLBACK == NULL" << std::endl;
    }
}
```

ida_a.cpp:

```
void IDA_A::Init(std::string vIdent){
    this->mXIDA = new XIDA( (void*) &this->IDA_Callback);
}
```

Now XIDA:

xida.h:

```
class XIDA{
public:
    XIDA(void *vPara);
};
```

xida.cpp:

```
XIDA_A m_XIDA_A;

XIDA::XIDA(void *vPara){
    std::cout << "TEST XIDA ---- A" << std::endl;
    m_XIDA_A.Init(vPara);
}
```

xida_a.h:

```
typedef int(*IDACallback) (void*, void*);

class XIDA_A{
private:
    IDACallback mIDACallback;
public:
    void Init(void *vPara);
}
```

xida_a.cpp:

```
1 void XIDA_A::Init(void *vPara){
2 int nErr = 0;
3    cout << "XIDA -- INIT A **************************************************  " << vPara << endl;
4   try{
5       this->mIDACallback = *static_cast < IDACallback* > (vPara);
6   } catch (...){
7       nErr = 1;
8    }
9   if(nErr == 0){
10      cout << "XIDA -- INIT B **************************************  " << this->mIDACallback << endl;
11      this->mIDACallback(NULL, NULL); // <------ HERE IS THE ERROR
12  }
13 }
```

While normal call (via terminal and path/bin) the error is:

```
Speicherzugriffsfehler (engl. memory access error <?>)
```

With Valgrind:

```
XIDA -- INIT A **************************************************  0x4e40a19
XIDA -- INIT B **************************************  1
==20001== Jump to the invalid address stated on the next line
==20001==    at 0x20EC8348E5894855: ???
==20001==    by 0x504C690: XIDA::XIDA(void*) (xida.cpp:10)
==20001==    by 0x4E405CB: IDA_A::Init(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >) (ida_a.cpp:37)
==20001==    by 0x4E3FE9F: IDA::IDA(char const*) (ida.cpp:13)
==20001==    by 0x401932: main (main.cpp:13)
==20001==  Address 0x20ec8348e5894855 is not stack'd, malloc'd or (recently) free'd
```

So, now I know where the error is, but I do not know how to fix it.

Comment: Please try to make a complete (compilable) example out of this. The declaration of `IDA_A:: init ()` is missing from the class, for example.

Comment: To fix this, replace all `void *`s by proper types, and let the compiler find the real bug for you, which will likely manifest itself as a compilation error, due to the wrong object being passed via the formerly-opaque `void *`. There are very few situations in modern C++ that still require the use of `void *`s, any more.

Comment: Question cannot be answered in it's current state without the use of magic, psychic power, or guesswork. Please assemble a [mcve]. Off topic, this code invites a lot of possible errors by ignoring some of the basic tenets of C++.

Comment: @ Sam Varshavchik: As I already wrote earlier I changed the void* paras into the typedef of the callback, which is working. But I still wanted to know how I can get it working with void*. And the solution is, instead of "this->mIDACallback = *static_cast < IDACallback* > (*vPara);", I can use "this->mIDACallback = (IDACallback) vPara;". You brought me to the point. Thank you, sir!

Answer (score 1):

`IDA_A::Init` is not actually declared, but aside from that you cast `vPara` (which contains a pointer to function) to a pointer to pointer to function and then dereference it:

```
this->mIDACallback = *static_cast < IDACallback* > (vPara);
```

should be

```
this->mIDACallback = static_cast < IDACallback > (vPara);
```

Comment: And if you disassemble `0x20EC8348E5894855` (taking into account that it's little-endian) you get a function prolog: `push rbp; mov rbp,rsp; sub rsp,0x20`

Comment: I get an error:
invalid static_cast from type 'void*' to type 'IDACallback {aka int (*)(void*, void*)}'
   this->mIDACallback = static_cast < IDACallback > (vPara);
                                                          ^

Comment: But in the code you posted it is declared differently as `typedef int(*IDACallback) (void*, void*);` and `static_cast` should work fine.

Comment: Yes, both, typedef and the function given as callback are equal int (void*, void*), but your solution isn't working. BTW, I also tried it before, also in other variations. That is one reason I posted here, because I do find the solution by my self, where I "normally" think, that this code should work..., but it is not.

Comment: @ Sam Varshavchik: I now have changed all void* into typedef int(void*, void*) and this works.
Now I will have again a further look with void*...
I will post the result.

Comment: @VTT: I'm not sure if I understand you... Where do I have that?

Comment: nvm, however the error description you wrote 'IDACallback {aka int ()(void, void*)}' doesn't match the code you posted where `'IDACallback` is `int(*)(void *, void *)`.

Comment: To be all the way correct:
Instead of void* I use the typedef like in the OP: 
typedef int(*IDACallback) (void*, void*); 
And the functions look like that now:
Function_Name(IDACallback vCallback);

Comment: @VTT: This was from changing with your suggestion..., to leave one asterix. This was not the error description from the OP.

Comment: My suggestion does not affect the type of `IDACallback` anyhow.